# Populate Column Using If Else Then Statement on another column in vba

Tags: vba

Column C starts off with a column of numbers in text format. Column H is blank, and I want to populate each corresponding row with text based on the results from an If Elseif statement focused on column C.

I keep getting a error. "Application-defined or object-defined error". So I changed the formatting of those cells. I've also have had the issue where it doesn't step through the entire column. That's why I added the For Loop.

Thank you!!

```
[C:C].Select
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With

For i = 1 To Rows.Count
Next i

If Cells(i, 3).Value = "40018" Then
    Cells(i, 8).String = "<0.100 W"
ElseIf Cells(i,3).Value="41020" Then
    Cells(i, 8).String = "asfsdfsfd"
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because your code example tried to assign a value to the property ".String" (as in Cells(i, 8)**.String** = "<0.100 W") which doesn't exist.  Also, your *If ElseIf* statement should be inside the For loop to work correctly.  Try the following code instead.

```
[C:C].Select
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With

For i = 1 To Rows.Count
    If Cells(i, 3).Value = "40018" Then
        Cells(i, 8).Value = "<0.100 W"
    ElseIf Cells(i, 3).Value = "41020" Then
        Cells(i, 8).Value = "asfsdfsfd"
    End If
Next I
```